# Use string value from one class in another class

Tags: c#

I've got some methods in one class that return values of to,from,message and im trying to use these in the other class that has the default display message.
I can't seem to use the string values that I get from the methods in class 1 in class 2. 
I have tried declaring the string values public but got overloaded with errors none of which really said why the error was happening.

```
    public class ChristmasCard
{

   public static void Main()
    {
         string toWhom = To();

         string fromWhom = From();

         double decorate = ChooseDecoration();

         string message = AddMessage();

         DoPromt(message);

         DisplayMessage(decorate);

         Console.ReadLine();

    }
public class ChristmasCardTesting : ChristmasCard
{

    public static void SantaA()
    {


        Console.WriteLine(ChristmasCard.toWhom);

        Console.WriteLine(ChristmasCard.Message1);

        Console.WriteLine(ChristmasCard.Message2);

        Console.WriteLine(ChristmasCard.Message3);

        Console.WriteLine(ChristmasCard.fromWhom);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess inheritance is not what you want here. You want to use an instance of your object instead.

**First** you want to create an instance of your ChristmasCard.
That instance should hold Properties/Fields of the values you like to hold in the RAM.

**Then** you want to create an instance of your ChristmasCardTesting and call the "testmethod" while giving the christmas card as parameter.

And that code could be executed in your Program.

I guess what you want to achieve should more like the following:

```
   public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            ChristmasCard card = new ChristmasCard();
            ChristmasCardController controller = new ChristmasCardController();
            controller.SomeMethod(card);
            WriteToConsole(card);
        }

        public static void WriteToConsole(ChristmasCard card) {
            Console.WriteLine(card.ToWhom);
            Console.WriteLine(card.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(card.FromWhom);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Pure data class does not needs methods!
    /// </summary>
    public class ChristmasCard {
        public string ToWhom { get; set; }
        public string FromWhom { get; set; }
        public double Decorate { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Controller for the dataClass
    /// </summary>
    public class ChristmasCardController {
        public void SomeMethod(ChristmasCard card) {
            card.ToWhom = To();
            card.FromWhom = From();
            card.Decorate = ChooseDecoration();
            card.Message = AddMessage();
            DoPromt(card);
            DisplayMessage(card.Decorate);
        }

        private void DisplayMessage(double cardDecorate) {
            //Write your message to the console
        }

        private void DoPromt(ChristmasCard card) {
            //Do some ConsoleRead in here
        }

        private string AddMessage() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private double ChooseDecoration() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private string From() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private string To() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**

If that is totally not what you want, please explain what you are trying to achieve and i'm 100% sure i'll find the answer.

**Edit2**

All methods from that Controller class could also be in the Program class.
Note these would have to be static if you move these methods. I hope this snipped makes it clear how to solve the problem.

Comment: So I've been asked to use 2 classes, and what im trying to do now is to pass the values that I got from the methods that give me the message, I want the message to go into the 2nd class so when the class is called the message is part of it. I attempted your code but my program just gives me errors that seem to be caused by the code somehow making the methods invalid

Comment: I fixed a possible error. You can not just copy paste the given code as solution. My intend was to show you the pattern, of course you'd have to add the To(), From(), etc. methods into the christmas card method. Gimme a second i refactore that snipped into a better way

Comment: I understand that part and I have those methods in there already and adapted it, the return value of the message now is just output as the namespace which I have no Idea how that has come about

Comment: Can you add your current status to your initial post?

Comment: All good forgot a } all sorted now, thanks for that now to power through with the rest of this thank you.

Comment: No problem, your welcome! Good luck with your Task :)